# Partial compilation with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm interested in partially compiling Java projects using Maven. By partially compiling, I mean to compile as much of the code as possible, and at least as much as can be compiled using the Eclipse compiler in IntelliJ.

In a Java project where not all files compile, I've managed to use the Eclipse compiler in IntelliJ to compile parts of the project that can be compiled. While I have managed to use the eclipse compiler using `plexus-compiler-eclipse` to make Maven not choke on compile errors while seemingly compile at least some files, I realized that when I rebuild the project in IntelliJ I actually get more runnable byte code, even for some methods in sources files that do not compile as a whole. This is rather useful when working with a broken code base, e.g. during large refactorings and similar, and I wonder if I can achieve the same result with Maven.

My goal is to have a Jenkins job that compiles as much of the code as it can, and runs the tests that are runnable. At the moment, I cannot do do an `mvn test` after having "compiled" the project using `plexus-compiler-eclipse`, likely because some of the code needed for test setup resides in files that can only be partially compiled. As a benchmark, I can actually do an `mvn test` if I have pre-compiled that project with IntelliJ.

Please note problem formulation. I'm interested in partial compilation as a development tool, and fixing the compilation errors will not provide me with the tool I seek.

I do realize that the problem may be a bit ill-posed, and if difficulties arise in answering it I guess I can try to work out a minimal workable example.

Comment: Have you tried setting [failOnError](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#failOnError) to `false`?

Comment: So you're trying to replicate Eclipse's mis-feature of generating Java classes from code that doesn't compile, producing output that behaves erradically? Maven is a serious development tool that disallows such behavior by design.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker: I have tried setting `failOnError` to false, and that doesn't accomplish what I want. Thanks, though.

Comment: @DanubianSailor, and others: Comments and answers that reject the problem statement without evidence that what I want to do cannot be done, need not to bother. Thank you!